# save dynamic input form data into database kendo ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, asp.net-web-api2

i have populated dynamic input form fields. its populated successfully.i do not have an idea how to save data into database by using put/post api. as i used get api.

> 1. html code

```
<div id="renderform" class="form horizontal-form form-body">
        <!-- container UL to host input fields -->
        <div class="row" data-template="fieldsTemplate" data-bind="source:fields">

        </div>
    <!-- button to save changes -->
    <button id="save" class="btn btn-circle  btn-sm btn-default" type="button">Save</button>
</div>
```

> 2. kendo template

```
<script id="fieldsTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" data-bind="attr: { for: name}, text: ItemLabel"></label>
        <div class="">
            <input class="form-control-static" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

> 3. ajax function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // retrieve the model from an API call
    $.ajax({
        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "FormItemsDesign/GetFormItemsDesignList?parentid=" + formdesignid,
        //url :"json.txt",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (model) {
            // convert the JSON to observable object
            var viewModel = kendo.observable(model);
            // bind the model to the container
            kendo.bind($("#renderform"), viewModel);
        }
    });
</script>
```

> 4. Post/Put api's will be like

```
url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "FormItemsDesign
type:Post
type:Put
```

please help me, how to make/use ajax function to call Post/Put to save/update data by each dynamic field into database. i appreciate your valuable time and effort thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading more articles finally I found this solution. Its working for me.

```
$("#save").on("click", function () {

        $("#renderform input").each(function () {
            var dataModel = {
                parentid: $(this).attr("id"),
                ItemOrder: "1",
                ItemFieldType: "1",
                ColWidth: "100",
                RowHeight: "100",
                ItemText: $(this).val(),
                ItemLabel: $(this).attr("name")
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "FormsItem?firmid=" + firmid + "&createdby=" + clientid,
                data: JSON.stringify(dataModel),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        });
        alert("Data Saved successfully");
    });
```